# Get site uri for switch statment

Tags: php, uri

How can I get the URL path for a switch statement? I tried `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but cant get it to work. Example:

```
$aPage = 'app/views/home.php';
            switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
            {
                case "home":
                    $aPage = "app/views/home.php";
                    break;

                case "how":
                    $aPage = "app/views/how.php";
                    break;

            }

            return $aPage;
```

So on root is shows: `$aPage = 'app/views/home.php` (which it does)

If the url was `http://localhost/how/` it would return the `$aPage = "app/views/how.php"`.

Right now I get a 404 The requested URL /how/ was not found on this server.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and you will likely see that it includes the slashes and such.

Comment: do you have an .htaccess file in place that points to your index.php ?

Comment: Yes, its local right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are then navigating to the `http://localhost/how/` URL and it is simply trying to find a directory on the server labeled "how" and not finding it. This is called routing and it is typically handled using a rewrite rule. Here is the basic idea:

- User hits your index.php file with no query string and gets served the default file. Generally your server will not show index.php in the address bar because it will simply load any file labeled "index".
- When you load a new template you append it as a query string parameter. Something like `http://localhost.com/?view=how`
- In your PHP file you can then get that variable using the `$_GET` varaible and do your logic (include a file, modify output, etc)

You then need to add a rewrite rule on the server side. With apache that is done by adding a file labeled `.htaccess` on the root of your server. Add this inside that file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [QSA]
```

This will take that URL and update it so that it looks like `http://localhost/how/` in the address bar, but is interpreted by PHP as having a query string parameter on your main index file. As for your switch statement it would change to look something like this:

```
$aPage = 'app/views/home.php';
switch( $_GET['view'] ) {
    case "home":
        $aPage = "app/views/home.php";
        break;
    case "how":
        $aPage = "app/views/how.php";
        break;
}

return $aPage;
```

Although it may be easier to just have your function logic to be more like this:

```
$route = $_GET['view'] ? $_GET['view'] : 'home'; // if view exists set it, if not default to 'home'
$validRoutes = array('home', 'how'); // array of acceptable routes

if( in_array( $route, $validRoutes ) ) {
    return sprintf('app/views/%s', $route);
}

return false; // return false if invalid
```